# doPost(e) with no result - Google script as API

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, web-applications, postman, http-post

I can't seem to get the simplest doPost to reply in Scripts, tried a few things from around the internet, and cannot get a Post to reply.
I have reduced it to as simple as possible to get a reply, as below.

```
function doPost(e) {

   var HTMLString = "<style> h1,p {font-family: 'Helvitica', 'Arial'}</style>" 
 + "<h1>Hello World!</h1>"
 + "<p>Welcome to the Web App";
 
 HTMLOutput = HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(HTMLString);
 Logger.log(HTMLOutput);
// Return plain text Output
 return ContentService.createTextOutput(HTMLOutput);


}
```

Deployment settings:
[image: Google deployment settings]

I am using postman to send the POST[image: screenshot of Postman result]
No result.

Any ideas?

Comment: When I saw your script, an object of "HtmlOutput" is returned by `return ContentService.createTextOutput(HTMLOutput);`. In this case, a text of "HtmlOutput" is returned. But, from your image, it is required to know your setting of Web Apps. If your Web Apps is deployed as `Execute as: Me` and `Who has access to the app: Anyone`, "HtmlOutput" is returned. When you reflect your latest script in your Web Apps, what result will you obtain? But, when Web Apps is redeployed as a new version, the URL is changed. Please be careful about this. By the way, what result do you want to obtain in your goal?

Comment: @Tanaike I have edited the question to show the deployment settings are "me" and "anyone"
Not sure what you mean by "Reflect your latest script" to obtain a result sorry, can you explain more?
The goal is to create an API, that will do things, but I haven't been able to get a result for a doPost at all. I have managed to doGet with a result, which is lovely, but I want the  Post version.

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your reply, I posted an answer to your question and your additional question. Could you please confirm it? If I misunderstood your question and your additional question and that was not useful, I apologize.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- I understood your setting of Web Apps from `I have edited the question to show the deployment settings are "me" and "anyone"`.
- About `Not sure what you mean by "Reflect your latest script" to obtain a result sorry, can you explain more?`, when you use Web Apps, it is required to prepare a script with Google Apps Script. In this case, when you modify your script, it is required to reflect the latest script to the current or a new version of the deployed Web Apps. Here, when the script is reflected in Web Apps as a new version, the deployment ID is changed. By this, the endpoint of Web Apps is also changed. I thought that in this case, it might not be useful for your situation. So, I proposed to reflect the latest script in Web Apps without changing the endpoint of Web Apps. If you cannot understand it, I thought that this post might be useful. [Ref (Author: me)](https://gist.github.com/tanaikech/ebf92d8f427d02d53989d6c3464a9c43)
- About `The goal is to create an API, that will do things, but I haven't been able to get a result for a doPost at all. I have managed to doGet with a result, which is lovely, but I want the Post version.`, unfortunately, in your current script, an object of "HtmlOutput" is `returned by return ContentService.createTextOutput(HTMLOutput);`. By this, a text of "HtmlOutput" is returned. If you want to put a value to Web Apps as the POSt method and you want to retrieve the returned value, how about the following modification?

  ```js
  function doPost(e) {
    return ContentService.createTextOutput(JSON.stringify(e));
  }
  ```

  - When you modified your script of Web Apps, please reflect the latest script to the Web Apps. In this case, when you want to use the endpoint of Web Apps without changing the endpoint, please check [this post](https://gist.github.com/tanaikech/ebf92d8f427d02d53989d6c3464a9c43).
  - For example, when the HTTP request is run by including the request body of `'{"key":"value"}'` as a text with the POST method, `{"parameter":{},"postData":{"contents":"'{\"key\":\"value\"}'","length":17,"name":"postData","type":"text/plain"},"parameters":{},"contextPath":"","contentLength":17,"queryString":""}` is returned.

#### Note:

- From your showing script, when you want to return your value of `HTMLString`, the modified script is as follows. But, in this case, the HTML is returned as text. Please be careful about this. If you want to see the rendered HTML, please use `doGet` and return `return HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(HTMLString);`.

  ```js
  function doPost(e) {
    var HTMLString = "<style> h1,p {font-family: 'Helvitica', 'Arial'}</style>"
      + "<h1>Hello World!</h1>"
      + "<p>Welcome to the Web App";
    HTMLOutput = HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(HTMLString).getContent();
    return ContentService.createTextOutput(HTMLOutput);
  }
  ```

#### Reference:

- [Taking advantage of Web Apps with Google Apps Script (Author: me)](https://github.com/tanaikech/taking-advantage-of-Web-Apps-with-google-apps-script)
- [Redeploying Web Apps without Changing URL of Web Apps for new IDE (Author: me)](https://gist.github.com/tanaikech/ebf92d8f427d02d53989d6c3464a9c43)

Comment: Thanks, that was helpful.
I think it was mostly about the need to redeploy everytime in order to get an output, but also the return service wasn't correctly outputing something useful.
So double thanks there! I got it working! Yaah

Comment: @Craig Lambie Thank you for your response. About `any ideas why this question was down voted? no comments or anything, just negative`, unfortunately, I don't have a clear answer about it. I apologize for this.